# Chaning MacVim's default shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, macvim, vim, zshrc

I currently have my default shell set to zsh in terminal.  However, upon execution `!echo $SHELL` in MacVim, it returns `/bin/bash`, which is obviously the shell that I don't want.  How can I set zsh as my default in MacVim?

Note: I've attempted to `:set shell=/bin/zsh` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `!echo $SHELL` may be wrong, `:set shell=/bin/zsh` does seem to work.

Like you, I also get `/bin/bash` for `!echo $SHELL`. But if I try to run a non-existent command:

```
:!blah
zsh:1: command not found: blah

shell returned 127
```

So it looks like the setting works, and commands will be executed in the right shell.

Comment: Musts be a bug.  Thank you sir.  Much appreciated!